# Overhead lights don't work but voltage meter shows sockets have power

Tags: circuit-breaker, circuit

Overhead lights don't go on but voltage tester shows voltage is reaching  sockets. Even when switch is turned off, meter shows voltage still reaching sockets. Receptacles on the same circuit  also show a charge with the voltage tester but appliances plugged in don't work.

Comment: `Even when switch is turned off, meter shows voltage still reaching sockets.` ... a long wire that is not connected to anything can present voltage in the same way

Comment: "I replaced a GFCI circuit breaker recently"  Take it out and see if the problems go away.

Comment: What kind of meter are you using??? Look up phantom voltages, and verify you have the feeder or hot on the GFCI line terminals. Even the highest end and especially high end meters can show 120 on a GFCI that is mis wired.

Answer (score 1):

Voltage testers can sometimes be tricky because they can show "phantom voltage" induced (well, capacitively coupled) from other wires.

However, the more likely problem is -- remember, current flows in *loops* -- and the safety ground wire is not a player.  So somewhere the loop is broken; if you're measuring voltage (hot to ground) then it's likely that side of the loop is OK. Check the neutral side.

The neutral side is trickier to test, because it's *supposed to be* near 0 volts.  However if it is broken, and a load is connected and turned on, then a disconnected neutral will float near 120V, and will give a voltage reading.

Comment: Thanks  for  your help!   It was  a  loose  neutral  wire.

Comment: @Belford The appropriate way to say "thank you" at StackExchange sites is to click the up vote arrow. Even better is to click the checkmark next to the answer. Doing that will also prevent the system from bumping your question to the top of the pile every now and then.

Comment: Oh, so *that’s* why that happens...